# How to format float to omit zeros at the end of the fraction

Tags: floating-point, format, precision, string-formatting, monkeyc

I'd like to format a float so that it has at most 3 fractional digits, but if the last fractional digit(s) are 0 then omit them.

```
input : expected output
1.1234 : 1.123
1.120 : 1.12
1.100 : 1.1
1.0 : 1
```

The language doesn't matter as long as it uses the standard formatting C strings, i.e: "%.3f"

The solution I came up with:

```
function formatShortFloat(value as Float) as String {
    var str = value.format("%.3f");
    var chars = str.toCharArray();
    var end;
    for (end = str.length() - 1; chars[end] == '0' && end > 0; --end) {
    }
    if (chars[end] == '.') {
        --end;
    }
    return str.substring(0, end + 1) as String;
}
```

or (note, this is Monkey C, there's no easier way to access a char of a string, but that's my problem, that's why I asked for "any language", even pseudo code):

```
function formatShortFloat(value as Float) as String {
    var str = value.format("%.3f");
    var end = str.length();
    var lastChar;
    do {
        lastChar = str.substring(end - 1, end);
        --end;
    } while ("0".equals(lastChar));
    if (".".equals(lastChar)) {
        --end;
    }
    return str.substring(0, end + 1) as String;
}
```

Comment: You say "the language doesn't matter" but that makes no sense. If I gave you a solution for COBOL would that be acceptable? FORTRAN? LISP? APL? Also, you're expected to show us the code you've written to solve the problem.

Comment: Also, if whatever language you're using doesn't provide a format specifier to do what you want the trivial solution is format the value then trim trailing zeros and the period if it's the last character.

Comment: @KurtisRader I know I am supposed to include my code, but the thing is that my code is there: "%.3f" Ideally I hope to get an answer in similar format. Like (hypotethical): "%.30f" If that exists. If I knew the answer I wouldn't ask, would I. I also have some code that looks for the 0-s and . ant the end and deletes them, but it's ugly, I'll include for you.

Comment: Most languages do not have any built-in formatting for “round to three decimal places but remove trailing zeroes and, if that leaves the point last, also remove the point.” So the solution is to round to three decimal places using a built-in feature and write code to remove trailing zeroes and, if that leaves the point last, also remove the point. And you already have that, so there is no remaining question here.

Comment: Yeah. Strange though, I'm pretty sure I'm not the 1st one who would like to display this "simplified" or "human friendly" format.

Comment: For the example values you gave "%.4g" works, but probably this does not produce what you want for numbers smaller than 1 or bigger than 10 (you did not say if that happens or what output you expect in that case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you always want 3 fractional digits (unless they are zero) and your format-function is compatible with C99 `printf`/`sprintf`, you can use the `%.*g` formatter and provide the number of desired total digits as an extra argument. Assuming your input numbers are not smaller than `0.001` the number you need to pass is `(int)(log10(x)+4.0)`. If smaller values occur, I would suggest to manually return `"+/-0.001"` or `"0"` depending on `x`.

Proof-of-concept (in C with some debugging output for comparison -- you can just remove everything starting from `\t` and the extra `x`):

```
void println(double x)
{
    printf("%.*g\t= %.99g\n", (int)(log10(fabs(x))+4.0), x, x);
}
```

Godbolt-Demo with some test cases: https://godbolt.org/z/zsxns4h9v

Comment: Nice! This is kind of what I was hoping for. Too bad "g" isn't supported in Monkey C.

Comment: @Gavriel If <The language doesn't matter as long as it uses the standard formatting C strings, i.e: "%.3f"> is really true then since this answer uses a standard formatting C string `"%.*g"`, then it is an acceptable answer to posted question.  If it is not acceptable because of <"g" isn't supported in Monkey C.>, then such restrictions deserved to have been on the original question.